Please install sqlite3 package manually
I get an npm error from the sequelize module when running the project via node:
"start": "node build/scripts/main.js"
webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:57
throw new Error(`Please install ${moduleName} package manually`);
^

I tried to install sqlite3 in the usual way:
npm i sqlite3
However, I encounter the problem of eternal installation, described here:
npm install sqlite3 takes forever
Now, I tried with the --build-from-source parameter, and the sqlite3 module was installed, but the problem with the module not found when running the project remained.
I also regularly encounter a problem finding the "pg-hstore" module in node_modules/sequelize. I solve it relatively simply, go to the last mentioned directory and install pg-hstore in the standard way. However, after a while pg-hstore crashes again. Perhaps the problem with this module is somehow related to the unsuccessful search for the sqlite3 package.
My package .json:
"dependencies": {
"@packages/build-config": "*",
"@packages/shared": "*",
"dotenv": "^16.4.5",
"express": "^4.21.1",
"sequelize": "^6.37.5",
"sqlite3": "^5.1.7"
}

My sequelize builder:
import { Sequelize, Options as SequelizeOptions } from 'sequelize';

let sequelizeConnectionOpts: SequelizeOptions = {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: '.db'
}
export default new Sequelize(
    sequelizeConnectionOpts,
);

Any ideas, suggestions, please?
